# iOS keep app always alive for home automation purpose

Tags: ios, swift, home-automation

I'm building home automation system for my house.
The plan is to have lots of different rfduino nodes talking to one wall mounted iPad through the bluetooth.

So far all working perfect apart from keeping an app alive all the time, device is plugged to the charger.

My question is rather simple and I struggle to find a solution.
How can I keep the app always alive to do its processing but with the  screen disabled?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try looking at Apple's [Background Execution Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). That is what apps like Pebble use to stay alive in the background.

Comment: Thanks, had a read through. And found this.   Uses Bluetooth LE accessories
bluetooth-central
The app works with a Bluetooth accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the Core Bluetooth framework.
Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory
bluetooth-peripheral
The app supports Bluetooth communication in peripheral mode through the Core Bluetooth framework.
Using this mode requires user authorization; for more information, see Supporting User Privacy.